# How to use Promise.all() after Promises created in for loop

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function foo() that includes a Promise that resolves inside a for loop. I want to run foo() several times, giving it different arguments each time. Then I want to do something with the results of all of that. Will Promise.all() run at the end of the for loops or after all of the Promises inside of foo() returned? Or will it say "none of these foo()s are Promises!" and laugh at me?

```
var foo = (x) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        someOtherFunctionThatReturnsAPromise(x).then(returnSomething());
    }
};

function nowDoEverything() {
    return Promise.all([foo(1), foo(2), foo(3)]).then(doSomethingWithAllThoseReturnedValues());
}

nowDoEverything();
```

Does foo() need to return a Promise? If so, how would I do so given that the Promises inside of foo() are generated inside the for loop?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all states that
"The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects."

This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRgAdi3gX-s is really good at explaining basic Promises, but I seem to be trying to do something that the architects did not intend/expect.

Comment: Closely related: [Promise.all is returning an array of undefined and resolves before being done](/q/34813147/4642212), [Promise.all is not waiting for the functions to finish](/q/50994427/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push promises to an array, `return` array from `foo`, omit `()` from function within `.then()` to avoid calling function immediately. Use spread element at `foo()` calls to return a single array of promises to `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()`.

```
var foo = (x) => {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        arr.push(someOtherFunctionThatReturnsAPromise(x).then(returnSomething));
    }
    return arr
};

function nowDoEverything() {
    return Promise.all([...foo(1), ...foo(2), ...foo(3)])
           .then(doSomethingWithAllThoseReturnedValues)
}

nowDoEverything()
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Great, thanks! What are the ellipsis (...foo(1)) for?

Comment: @GlenPierce `...` punctuator can be spread element or rest element depending on usage, see [What is SpreadElement in ECMAScript documentation? Is it the same as Spread operator at MDN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper). Without spread element, there will be three, or N-times `foo` calls arrays at array passed to `.then()` from `Promise.all()` instead of single array. `Promise.all([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]).then(data => console.log(data)); Promise.all([...[1,2,3], ...[4,5,6]]).then(data => console.log(data))`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right. Here is the signature of `Promise.all()`:

```
Promise.all<T>: (Iterable<Promise<T>): Promise<T[]>
```

Basically, it accepts an iterable of Promises, and returns itself a Promise.

By passing the results of `foo()`, `foo()` is expected to return a Promise itself, else it wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, it would immediately resolve to `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

Comment: @Ryan Right, which isn't very helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `foo()` needs to return a promise. You can add each promise to an array and use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them:

```
var foo = x => {
    var results = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        results.push(
            someOtherFunctionThatReturnsAPromise(x)
                .then(returnSomething)
        );
    }

    return Promise.all(results);
};
```